# why does the opacity transition not work and the Jobs component suddenly appears without opacity transition?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, styles, opacity

I made a toggle function that calls from the button and i dont understand why the Jobs component who receives the styles appears suddenly without without transitioning.
I want that the opacity.
I want the opacity to increase until the component displays slowly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import './Experience.css';
class Experience extends Component {


    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = { display: 'none', opacity: 0 }
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this)
      }
      
    
    toggle() {
        console.log("ENTRO EN TOOGLE")
        if (this.state.display === 'none') {
        this.setState({ display: 'block' })
        setTimeout(() =>
            this.setState({ opacity: 1 }), 300
        )
        }
        else {
        this.setState({ opacity: 0 })
        setTimeout(() =>
            this.setState({ display: 'none' }), 900
        )
        }
    }
  
    styles = (e) => {
        console.log(e)
    }

    render() {
    
    const styles = this.state;

    const { t } = this.props;

    return (
    <div>
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="row mt-top">                 
            <div className="col xl4 l4 m6 s12">     
              <button onClick={this.toggle}>DESPLEGAR</button>
            </div>
            <Jobs  style={styles}></Jobs>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default withTranslation()(Experience);
```

Answer (score 0):

what you're attempting is like wanting to call a function without calling it when you want an element to transition you need to call the transition CSS property
something like this.

```
.name {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.name:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```